# Evaluating python block at module level

Tags: org-babel, python

So apparently org-babel is evaluating python code inside its own function, perhaps when calling the interpreter or to be able to return the `#+RESULTS:` I guess. How to instruct it to evaluate the same way that the python mode does (say `C-c '` and `C-c C-c`) ?

Example :

```
#+Begin_src python
from math import *
#+end_src
```

Evaluating to python3 directly from org spits in `Org-Babel Error Output` :

```
  File "<stdin>", line 2 
SyntaxError: import * only allowed at module level
```

Python 2.7 being more permissive, illustrating the situation called for a different example

```
#+Begin_src python 
from Tkinter import *

class MainWindow():
   def __init__(self,parent):
        # the following line stumbles on the problem
        Frame(self , parent)            
        pass

Tk()
#+end_src
```

I'm pretty sure there's an option to bypass the case. What could it be ?

Comment: try using `#+Begin_src python :session`

Comment: Thanks. Found the answer while finishing to read the babel docs and redacting the post in the meantime... http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/intro.html#source-code-execution

Comment: you can answer your own question, if you found out the answer

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [babel introduction](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/intro.html#orgheadline14) : Setting the system wide header argument `:session`

> run an interactive session as an "inferior process" within Emacs. This
>   means that an environment is created containing data objects that
>   persist between different source code blocks.
>
> Also, in non-session mode, the python code block will be wrapped in a
>   function